# how to reflect sorting index on another list item

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I've two different lists

```
<ul id="one">
    <li id="num_1">One</li>
    <li id="num_2">two</li>
    <li id="num_3">Three</li>
    <li id="num_4">Four</li>
</ul>
<ul id="two">
    <li id="recordsArray_1">1: First</li>
    <li id="recordsArray_2">2: Second</li>
    <li id="recordsArray_3">3: Third</li>
    <li id="recordsArray_4">4: Fourth</li>
</ul>
```

I've my jQuery Codes as

```
$(function() {
    $("#two").sortable({ opacity: 0.6, cursor: 'move', update: function() {
    // Do stuffs                                             
}                                 
});
```

Here, What I want to do is, as I drag any element in `#two`, I want the corresponding item in `#one` to reflect as I drag.

Say for example I drag `#recordsArray_3` to top of the list `#two`, then `#num_3` will follow up and be placed on top of the list `#one`.

So can anyone direct me how to link the two list-items??